# Как показать эффект нажатия на айтем

Tags: android, listview

Нужно реализовать эффект нажатия на айтем `ListView`. Только эффект. Тоесть, если в слушателе списка есть код, то он не должен выполняться. Такую реализацию видел в настройках прошивки CyanogenMod 12, там если в поиске найти настройку, перекидывает на экран, где находится эта настройка и как бы показывает куда нажать)

Comment: Нужно именно нажать или просто показать куда нажать?

Comment: @Herrgott, просто показать)

Comment: я бы сделал просто добавлением элемента с анимацией в определенных точках, где находится элемент. И после завершения анимации удалил бы этот элемент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ListView
...
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_effect"/>
```